# mouse.isPressedIn method not working with new touch screen

Tags: psychopy

We're having a problem getting our new Ilyama ProLite T2452MTS to work with mouse click responses, when using PsychoPy's mouse.isPressedIn method.

To summarise, older touchscreens and mouse responses work fine, but the new touch screen does not. The new touchscreen works fine in Windows and with pop-up text boxes in PsychoPy, so I think the problem lies with the mouse.isPressedIn method somewhere. Only dragging one's finger within the box will trigger a response.

Here is my code.

```
win = visual.Window(size=(1920, 1080), fullscr=True, screen=0, allowGUI=False, allowStencil=False,
    monitor='testMonitor', color=[1,1,1], colorSpace='rgb',
    blendMode='avg', useFBO=True,
    )

rectangle = visual.Rect(win=win, name='Bluebox',
    width=[0.3, 0.5][0], height=[0.3, 0.5][1],
    ori=0, pos=[0.25, 0],
    lineWidth=1, lineColor=[0,0,1], lineColorSpace='rgb',
    fillColor=[0,0,1], fillColorSpace='rgb')
mouse = event.Mouse(win=win)

rectangle.draw()
win.flip()

test = True
while test:

    if mouse.isPressedIn(rectangle) == True:

        test = False
    else:
        rectangle.draw()
        win.flip()
```

Many thanks,
David

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is two years later and you've probably solved it, but for other interested people:

For touch screen I've found it's better to use `.contains()` as they are a bit temperamental with deciding what's a click. To do this you'd change your code to:

```
test = True
while test:

    if rectangle.contains(mouse):
        test = False
    else:
        rectangle.draw()
        win.flip()
```

At times it might be useful to reset the position of your cursor to stop it being registered as in a shape. To do this have `from win32api import SetCursorPos` at the top of your script. Then when you want to set the cursor position just use `SetCursorPos((0,0))`, where the two values are x and y coordinates in pixels. It's probably a good habit to do this frequently, e.g. after exiting any `while` loop.